# Zend Mail problem with foreign char + comma

Tags: php, email, zend-framework, sendmail

Zend Mail throws an exception (because mail() returns false) when the to name is set to something with both a foreign character (like "å") and a comma (","). Re-produce with code below.

```
$mail = new Zend_Mail('utf-8');
$mail
    ->setFrom('info@myhost', 'My company')
    ->setSubject('hi')
    ->addTo('MYEMAIL@SOMEHOST.COM', 'aå,a')
    ->setBodyHtml('<p>asd</p>')
    ->send();
```

If I change the addTo call to something of the below, no error occurs.

```
->addTo('znarkus@gmail.com', 'aåa')
->addTo('znarkus@gmail.com', 'a,a')
->addTo('znarkus@gmail.com', 'aa')
```

The weird thing is, even though it throws an exception ("Unable to send mail"), *the mail is delivered*. I'm running the latest Zend Mail (1.9.5?). Please halp!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that mail() function for $to accepts

```
User <user@example.com>, Another User <anotheruser@example.com>
```

and I guess that PHP internally splits the string on commas to separate multiple recipients but you are providing only one email address.

If you think this is a Zend_Mail, or PHP bug you should post this to the appropriate issue tracker.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a bug in Zend_Framework:

http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-10792

a comma is allowed in the name part of the e-mail:

"Smith, Frank"

this is okay

Answer (score 0):

The comma is a reserved literal in the "to" part of a mail header (and you should never use it though), separating different targets. Even if your "first" mail gets sent, imho it creates a header like this:

```
aå, a <znarkus@gmail.com>
```

With this header i assume your mta tries to send two mails: one to aå, which fails (badly), and a second one to znarkus@gmail.com, which should make its way.
You could try to look into the mail headers to confirm this theory.